# How to resolve timeout errors while uploading large PCA models using MLflow?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlflow

I am trying to upload a PCA model (trained using sklearn) to a custom ec2 server. The size of the model is 1.5Gb. I am receiving timeout errors despite increasing the timeout to 900. I tried to use the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2401), but setting environment variable does not work

The server configurations during the code run were

```
[Unit]
Description=Mlflow server configuration
[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/:$PATH exec mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8883 --artifacts-destination s3://icad-mlflow-artifacts --serve-artifacts --backend-store-uri /home/ubuntu/mlruns --gunicorn-opts "--log-level debug --timeout 900 --graceful-timeout 120"'
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The code that could reproduce the issue is

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json
import mlflow.pytorch
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pk

folder = 'enter the path of folder'
images = \[\]
image_names = \[\]
count =0
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
img = np.resize(img,(90, 360))
\# print(img.shape)
if img is not None:
\# print(len(img.flatten()/255))
images.append(img.flatten()/255)
image_names.append(filename)

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("mention your tracking uri")
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name="your experiment name")
exp = 'some random name'

with mlflow.start_run(run_name=exp) as run:
print("run started")
pca_2000 = PCA(n_components=7000)
pca_2000_reduced = pca_2000.fit_transform(images)
pk.dump(pca_2000, open("pca_test_cat.pkl","wb"))
print("started upload")
model_info = mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=pca_2000, artifact_path="pca_cat_dog",registered_model_name= "pca_model_test_notuseful")
```

For the purpose of testing I had used cat dog dataset available on Kaggle, but one can use any dataset as long as the size of PCA model >= 1.5Gb.

Stack trace

```
2023/05/25 19:22:47 WARNING mlflow.sklearn: Model was missing function: predict. Not logging python_function flavor!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1001, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<server url>', port=8883): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/586086446372044084/031b643c33c54003a364e1a26369ff7b/artifacts/pca_cat_dog/model.pkl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\rest_utils.py", line 167, in http_request
    return _get_http_response_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\rest_utils.py", line 98, in _get_http_response_with_retries
    return session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<server url>', port=8883): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/586086446372044084/031b643c33c54003a364e1a26369ff7b/artifacts/pca_cat_dog/model.pkl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\someting\OneDrive - iCAD Dental\Desktop\git_igps\clustering\training_code_pca\pca_mnist.py", line 39, in <module>
    model_info = mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=pca_2000, artifact_path="pca_cat_dog",registered_model_name= "pca_model_test_notuseful")
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\sklearn\__init__.py", line 424, in log_model
    return Model.log(
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\model.py", line 552, in log
    mlflow.tracking.fluent.log_artifacts(local_path, mlflow_model.artifact_path)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 817, in log_artifacts
    MlflowClient().log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py", line 1069, in log_artifacts
    self._tracking_client.log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\client.py", line 448, in log_artifacts
    self._get_artifact_repo(run_id).log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\artifact\http_artifact_repo.py", line 40, in log_artifacts
    self.log_artifact(os.path.join(root, f), artifact_dir)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\artifact\http_artifact_repo.py", line 25, in log_artifact
    resp = http_request(self._host_creds, endpoint, "PUT", data=f)
  File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\rest_utils.py", line 185, in http_request
    raise MlflowException(f"API request to {url} failed with exception {e}")
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to <server url>:8883/api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/586086446372044084/031b643c33c54003a364e1a26369ff7b/artifacts/pca_cat_dog/model.pkl failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='<server url>', port=8883): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/586086446372044084/031b643c33c54003a364e1a26369ff7b/artifacts/pca_cat_dog/model.pkl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts like yours are not the matter of mlflow alone, but also depend on the server configuration. For instance, users reported [problems when uploading large models to Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3478).

Given the issue is server-specific we can have problems fully reproducing it, but for a starter, I suggest to:

1. set **env variables controlling uploading artefacts**
   https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.environment_variables.html#mlflow.environment_variables.MLFLOW_ARTIFACT_UPLOAD_DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT
2. check what is **the effect of your timeout flags**, under `--gunicorn-opts`, send to [`mlflow server` in CLI](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-server).